# Comparing 8 different Disjoint-Set data structure variants in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, comparative-review, library

The [Wikipedia page on Disjoint-Set data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) presents \$4\$ distinct algorithms for finding the root node of the tree, and \$2\$ distinct algorithms for performing the union operation. In this post, I will present all \$4 * 2\$ combinations:

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSet`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements the 
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure">
 * disjoint-set data structure</a>.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021).
 */
public final class DisjointSet<E> {

    private final Map<E, DisjointSetNode<E>> disjointSetMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The disjoint set root finder.
     */
    private final AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> disjointSetRootFinder;

    /**
     * The disjoint set operation provider.
     */
    private final AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer<E> disjointSetUnionComputer;

    /**
     * Constructs a disjoint-set data structure with specific operation 
     * implementations.
     * 
     * @param disjointSetRootFinder the root finder operation implementation 
     * object.
     * 
     * @param disjointSetUnionComputer the union operation implementation 
     * object.
     */
    public DisjointSet(AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> disjointSetRootFinder,
                       AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer<E> disjointSetUnionComputer) {

        this.disjointSetRootFinder = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        disjointSetRootFinder, 
                        "The input DisjointSetRootFinder is null.");

        this.disjointSetUnionComputer = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        disjointSetUnionComputer, 
                        "The input DisjointSetUnionComputer is null.");

        this.disjointSetRootFinder.ownerDisjointSet = this;
        this.disjointSetUnionComputer.ownerDisjointSet = this;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the root of the tree to which {@code item} belongs to.
     * 
     * @param item the target item.
     * @return the root of the tree to which {@code item} belongs to.
     */
    public E find(E item) {
        return disjointSetRootFinder.find(item);
    }

    /**
     * Unites the two trees into one, unless the two items already belong to the
     * same tree.
     * 
     * @param item1 the first item.
     * @param item2 the second item.
     */
    public void union(E item1, E item2) {
        disjointSetUnionComputer.union(item1, item2);
    }

    DisjointSetNode<E> find(DisjointSetNode<E> node) {
        if (node == node.getParent()) {
            return node;
        }

        return find(node.getParent());
    }

    DisjointSetNode<E> getNode(E item) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node = disjointSetMap.get(item);

        if (node == null) {
            node = new DisjointSetNode<E>(item);
            disjointSetMap.put(item, node);
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetNode`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the nodes of the disjoint-set data structures.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 4, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 4, 2021)
 */
final class DisjointSetNode<E> {

    /**
     * The actual item being held.
     */
    private final E item;

    /**
     * The parent node of this node.
     */
    private DisjointSetNode<E> parent;

    /**
     * The rank of this node. The rank of a node is its maximum height from any
     * leaf node.
     */
    private int rank;

    /**
     * The size of this node. The size of a node is the number of nodes under
     * it.
     */
    private int size;

    public DisjointSetNode(E item) {
        this.item = item;;
        this.parent = this; 
    }

    public E getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public DisjointSetNode<E> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + item + "]";
    }

    void setParent(DisjointSetNode<E> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for for root finding algorithms in a 
 * disjoint-set data structure.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public abstract class AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> {

    DisjointSet<E> ownerDisjointSet;

    /**
     * If {@code item} belongs to a tree, returns the root of that three. 
     * Otherwise, a trivial, empty tree {@code T} is created, and {@code item} 
     * is added to {@code T}.
     * 
     * @param item the query item.
     * @return the root of the tree to which {@code item} belongs to.
     */
    public abstract E find(E item);
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for the union computer algorithms in a 
 * disjoint-set data structure.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite date type.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public abstract class AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer<E> {

    DisjointSet<E> ownerDisjointSet;

    /**
     * If both {@code item1} and {@code item2} belong to the same tree, does 
     * nothing. Otherwise, unites the two into a single tree.
     * 
     * @param item1 the first item.
     * @param item2 the second item;
     */
    public abstract void union(E item1, E item2);
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the root finding algorithm for the disjoint-set data
 * structure using iterative path compression.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder<E>
extends AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public E find(E item) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item));

        DisjointSetNode<E> root = node;

        while (root.getParent() != root) {
            root = root.getParent();
        }

        while (node.getParent() != root) {
            DisjointSetNode<E> parent = node.getParent();
            node.setParent(root);
            node = parent;
        }

        return root.getItem();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the root finding algorithm for the disjoint-set data
 * structure using recursive path compression.
 *
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder<E>
extends AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public E find(E item) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item));

        if (node == node.getParent()) {
            return node.getItem();
        }

        node.setParent(ownerDisjointSet.find(node.getParent()));
        return node.getParent().getItem();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the root finding algorithm for the disjoint-set data
 * structure using path halving.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder<E>
extends AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public E find(E item) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node =
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item));

        while (node.getParent() != node) {
            node.setParent(node.getParent().getParent());
            node = node.getParent();
        }

        return node.getItem();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 *
 * This class implements the root finding algorithm for the disjoint-set data
 * structure using path splitting.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder<E>
extends AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder<E> {

    @Override
    public E find(E item) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node =
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item));

        while (node.getParent() != node) {
            DisjointSetNode<E> parent = node.getParent();
            node.setParent(parent.getParent());
            node = parent;
        }

        return node.getItem();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the union operation by rank.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer<E> 
extends AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer<E> {
    
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public void union(E item1, E item2) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node1 = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item1));

        DisjointSetNode<E> node2 = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item2));

        if (node1 == node2) {
            return;
        }

        if (node1.getRank() < node2.getRank()) {
            DisjointSetNode<E> tempNode = node1;
            node1 = node2;
            node2 = tempNode;
        }

        node2.setParent(node1);

        if (node1.getRank() == node2.getRank()) {
            node1.setRank(node1.getRank() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset;

/**
 * This class implements the union operation by tree size.
 * 
 * @param <E> the satellite data type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 5, 2021)
 */
public final class DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer<E>
extends AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer<E> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public void union(E item1, E item2) {
        DisjointSetNode<E> node1 = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item1));

        DisjointSetNode<E> node2 = 
                ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item2));

        if (node1 == node2) {
            return;
        }

        if (node1.getSize() < node2.getSize()) {
            DisjointSetNode<E> tempNode = node1;
            node1 = node2;
            node2 = tempNode;
        }
        // Here, node1.getSize() >= node2.getSize()
        node2.setParent(node1);
        node1.setSize(node1.getSize() + node2.getSize());
    }
}
```

### Repository

The entire story is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/disjoint-sets).

The typical benchmark output might be:

```
Seed: 1630845583522
The benchmark graph is built in 222 milliseconds.

................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer
Duration: 149 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer
Duration: 4670 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer
Duration: 153 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer
Duration: 4649 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer
Duration: 157 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer
Duration: 4645 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer
Duration: 141 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
Root finder: DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer
Duration: 4633 ms. Total edges: 199997. Total weight: 36417.94367839121.
................................................................................
1. Root finder: DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer, 141 milliseconds.
2. Root finder: DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer, 149 milliseconds.
3. Root finder: DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer, 153 milliseconds.
4. Root finder: DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer, 157 milliseconds.
5. Root finder: DisjointSetPathSplittingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer, 4633 milliseconds.
6. Root finder: DisjointSetPathHalvingNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer, 4645 milliseconds.
7. Root finder: DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer, 4649 milliseconds.
8. Root finder: DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder, union computer: DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer, 4670 milliseconds.
```

### Critique request

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind. In particular, is there any way to put the implementation classes into an implementation package (perhaps `com.github.coderodde.util.disjointset.impl`)?

Comment: Why prefer `abstract class` to `interface` for `[defining] the API`?

Comment: I think there is one big mess starting with a naming confusion between nodes (undirected graph↔"disjoint-set forest") and not the intended methods getting called. Probably, it is unfortunate to not specify `RootFinder` to find the root *disjoint-set forest node*. (How did you build confidence the intended ones got called?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't many best practices on how to package classes, a rule of thumb is to package classes of a module/feature together in a way so that they aren't strongly coupled together. If you were to make a `...disjointset.impl` and a `...disjointset.abstr` pack for example, you'd couple them together strongly since you can't use the implementations without the abstract base classes.

On the other hand, creating something like `...disjointset.finder` and `...disjointset.computer` works if the finders can compile without the computers and vice versa. I might have overlooked something, but they only seem to rely on `DisjointSet` and `DisjointSetNode` which would stay in the "root" `...disjointset` package so it would work.

The result would look like this:

```
com/github/coderodde/util/disjointset/
--> computers/
--> finders/
--> DisjointSet.java
--> DisjointSetNode.java

com/github/coderodde/util/disjointset/computers
--> AbstractDisjointSetUnionComputer.java
--> DisjointSetUnionByRankComputer.java
--> DisjointSetUnionBySizeComputer.java

com/github/coderodde/util/disjointset/finders
--> AbstractDisjointSetRootFinder.java
--> DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionRootFinder.java
--> DisjointSetPathHalvingRootFinder.java
--> DisjointSetPathSplittingRootFinder.java
--> DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionRootFinder.java
```

**You could also keep the package as it is**. It's not too big and it all has to do with manipulating a `DisjointSet`, so adding further layers might not even be necessary! For comparison, [this mp3 library](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mpatric/mp3agic) just puts all files into its main package and it has a lot more files.

For some further info, [this text](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) on how to divide an app into packages is a very interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

## Logic

If you're using Java 8+, in `getNode` I think you can simplify the logic using [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) like this

```java
return disjointMapSet.computeIfAbsent(item, () -> new DisjointSetNode<>(item));
```

Is there a reason not to implement `equals` / `hashcode` for the `DisjointSetNode` classes? Relying on reference equality seems less easier to reason about than using the `equals` method.

In `DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder#find`, what is the purpose of

```java
while (root.getParent() != root) {
  root = root.getParent();
}
```

shouldn't `ownerDisjointSet.find(ownerDisjointSet.getNode(item))` return the root of the tree or am I misreading this?

In `DisjointSetRecursivePathCompressionNodeFinder`, what is the purpose of `node == node.getParent()` - won't the `if` always be true since `DisjointSet#find` only returns when `node == node.getParent()`?

## Naming and Organization

Is there a reason why `DisjointSetNode` is not an inner `class` called `Node` scoped to the `DisjointSet` class itself? It feels like that would narrow the scoping of `DisjointSetNode` without having to worry about name-spacing with a prefix like `DisjointSet`.

The relationship between the `Abstract` classes and the `DisjointSet` class seems circular - `DisjointSet` relies on these `Abstract` classes but then the `Abstract` classes rely on the `DisjointSet`. I feel like the `Abstract` classes are better represented by `interface`s (since there's really no shared logic between the implementations of the `Abstract` classes except the shared dependency. The only thing these `Abstract` classes depend on the `DisjointSet` to get are the `root` nodes - what if these were passed to the concrete implementations of the `Abstract` classes?

Some other minor things are the naming for variables like `disjointSetMap` which is probably more descriptive as `itemsToNodes` or something of that nature. Or `getNode` is more like `getOrCreateNode`.

Comment: *In `DisjointSetIterativePathCompressionNodeFinder.find()`, what is the purpose of [iteratively finding the root]?* I think that part implements the first pass of the two-pass algorithm presented in the hyperlinked en.wikipedia article. Now about all those introductory calls to `ownerDisjointSet.find()`…

Comment: (One conceivable reason for `DisjointSetNode` not being an inner class of `DisjointSet` is that it doesn't need to know its instantiating instance - that leaves the question: Why not *nested*?)

Answer (score 0):

Jae Bradley raises a very [valid concern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269015/93149):
The use of `ownerDisjointSet.find()` on the node found by `owner….getNode(item)` prevents the differences in root finding algorithms to have any effect.
To compound to the problem, union computation does *not use `disjointSetRootFinder`, but `ownerDisjointSet.find()`.

---

From one step back, you
- try *multiple inheritance* without language support using manual *double dispatch*.
- miss the baseline cases:
  - *no* path shortening
  - union by seat-of-pants (first/second/random item gets to be parent)

Many problems start with the way we *think about things*, intimately related to *naming*.
And one crux in this regard is *unhelpful established names* such as
*disjoint-set data structure*,
*union–find data structure*,
*disjoint-set forest* - every one of them too long (and an indication that a concept may not (yet) be optimally formed&established). While `DisjointSets` wouldn't be wrong, I'd slightly prefer `PartitionedSet`.

One thing that doesn't sit well with me is `DisjointSetNode` sporting an `int rank` and an `int size` at the same time.

---

What if we ditch `…Node`?

- Have a Map not from item(payload) to `…Node`, but to *parent (item)*.

  - asked for "the" representative of the set

    - an unknown item *i* is in, return *i*
    - for known items, do "the walk"
  - union of sets specified by two items as usual

    - by seat-of-pants (use with path shortening, only)
      (a pity Java does not provide an attractive way to return more than one value - the number of steps taken in finding each representative would open an interesting can of worms)
    - for by-rank or by-size (do you want to update these in case of path shortening?)
      have Maps `item2size`&`item2rank`, `get()` overridden using `getOrDefault()` suitably instead of creating entries for leaves, initially null.
      On first access, instantiate appropriate Map.
      On subsequent accesses, check other Map for being null.

---

My benchmark results using a 1.8 JRE stopped to look arbitrary after urging to collect garbage before `duration = runKruskalsAlgorithm(rootFinder, unionComputer)` (From GitHub repository, not presented for review.
(`findMinimumSpanningTree(graph, weightFunction)` is odd for constructing the result not from its `minimumSpanningTree`.))